# Why can't I add a delay with the "/l" parameter in shutdown in os in python?

Tags: python-3.x

os.system("shutdown /l")
Can it have the "/t" parameter?

It gave me a long list of things that support the shutdown function but it did not run effectively. I was not sure why though. And why do the other parameters support the delay function "/t" but "/l" does not.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You are calling `os.system`, so your question is not about python-3.x but about running a command. For that SuperUser or Unix&Linux (both sister site of us, link on top right icons) are more appropriate. But before that: did you ever tried your command in a terminal, to check about messages and errors? It should give you a lot of hints (note: shutdown is a system program, not standardized, so you should RTFM of your target computer)

Answer (score 0):

Because `/t` requires an additional parameter, for the time-out period, while `/l` doesn't take any extra parameters:

```
C:\Users\BoppreH>shutdown /?
...
    /l         Log off. This cannot be used with /m or /d options.
...
    /t xxx     Set the time-out period before shutdown to xxx seconds.
               The valid range is 0-315360000 (10 years), with a default of 30.
               If the timeout period is greater than 0, the /f parameter is
               implied.
```

So try `os.system("shutdown /t 30")` instead.

Comment: I love the fact it has the ability to shut down 10 years in the future :-)